# Does Azure storage premium account support block blob?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

just created a few premium azure storage accounts with general-purpose v2, but it seem doesn't support block blob, when I try to upload from either Portal or Data Explorer, only option is page blob. but according document, general purpose v2 should support all 3 blob types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premium V2 storage accounts do not support Block Blobs. They only support Page Blobs and local redundancy level (LRS). If you need support for all kinds of blobs (Append, Block and Page) in a single storage account, you would need to create a "Standard" kind of account.

You would need to create a `BlockBlobStorage` kind of account if you want premium performance for Block blobs. Please note that this kind of account only supports Block blobs.

[image]

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-performance-tiers.